# WooCommerce always showing 0 as order ID on Order Received Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

we are facing a rare issue, WooCommerce is always showing 0 as order ID on the order received page

Anyone has an idea on how we can solve this?

[image]

[www.cosmeto.tn](https://www.cosmeto.tn)

Best
Ahmed

Comment: Have you changed the template of the order received page? Looks custom to me.

Comment: Deactivate all plugins except WooCommerce. Then check the issue by switching to storefront theme.